# Isotope multi-sort with a mixture of ascending and descending

Tags: jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm using the [Isotope jQuery plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to sort some tabular data.  That's all working fine, but now I need to sort on multiple columns, which is [documented](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html).

The problem is that some of the columns need to be sorted ascending, and other descending.  According to the documentation Isotope works by setting a set of values and a direction for those values, and not a mixture of the two.  See below:

```
var $container = $('#multiple-sort-by .isotope').isotope({
  // sort by color then number
  sortBy: [ 'color', 'number' ],
  sortAscending: true
});
```

Is it possible?

Syntax I would expect might be:

```
var $container = $('#multiple-sort-by .isotope').isotope({
  // sort by color then number
  sortBy: {
      [ 'color', 'asc' ],
      [ 'number', 'desc' ],
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a different area of the documentation that outlines how to do this.  Instead of my suggested syntax, you can instead provide an object to `sortAscending`.

EG:

```
$container.isotope({ 
    sortBy: sortValue,
    sortAscending: {
        color: true,
        number: false,
    }
});
```